# PHP - Update a dos tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de actualizar datos de dos tablas a la vez. Todo funciona bien, puedo extraer los datos y modificar los campos que deseo, pero a la hora de guardarlos no realiza esa función.

En consola no muestra ningún tipo de error y no encuentro el motivo por que el no realiza esa función, el único detalle que no estoy seguro es de los `where` si con el numero de correlativo que tienen en común puede funcionar o si necesita que sea por **id**, aún así he probado con ambos pero no da un resultado diferente

Este es mi código:

```
//TODO: UPDATE DE FORMULAS
  public function agrega_formula()
  {
    $str = '';
    $formula = array();
    $formula = json_decode($_POST['arrayformula']);
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    foreach ($formula as $k => $v) {
      $cantidad = $v->cantidad;
      $id_Mprima = $v->id_Mprima;
      $materiales = $v->materiales;
      $unidadm = $v->unidadm;
      $moneda = $v->moneda;
      $precio = $v->precio;
      $importe = $v->importe;
      //$total = $v->total;
      $estado = $v->estado;

      $rinde = $v->rinde;
      $costo = $v->costo;
      $numero_Dproducto = $v->numero_Dproducto;

      $productoc = $v->productoc;
      $categoria = $v->categoria;
      $id_Dproducto = $v->id_Dproducto;
      $id_detalle_Dproducto = $v->id_detalle_Dproducto;
      $total = $_POST["total"];
      $id_usuario = $_POST["id_usuario"];
      $id_producto = $_POST["id_producto"];

      $sql = "update detalle_Dproducto set     
      productoc=?,
      id_Mprima=?,
      materiales=?,
      unidadm=?,
      moneda=?,
      precio=?,
      cantidad=?,
      importe=?,
      id_usuario=?,
      now(),
      id_producto=?,
      estado=?
      where
      numero_Dproducto=?
  
      ";
      $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);

      $sql->bindValue(1, $productoc);
      $sql->bindValue(2, $id_Mprima);
      $sql->bindValue(3, $materiales);
      $sql->bindValue(4, $unidadm);
      $sql->bindValue(5, $moneda);
      $sql->bindValue(6, $precio);
      $sql->bindValue(7, $cantidad);
      $sql->bindValue(8, $importe);
      $sql->bindValue(9, $id_usuario);
      $sql->bindValue(10, $id_producto);
      $sql->bindValue(11, $estado);
      $sql->bindValue(12, $numero_Dproducto);

      $sql->execute();
    }
    $sql2 = "update Dproducto set
    now(),
    productoc=?,
    rinde=?,
    costo=?,
    categoria=?,
    moneda=?,
    subtotal=?,
    total=?,
    estado=?,
    id_producto=?,
    id_usuario=?,
    where
    numero_Dproducto=?
    ";
    $sql2 = $conectar->prepare($sql2);
    $sql2->bindValue(1, $productoc);
    $sql2->bindValue(2, $rinde);
    $sql2->bindValue(3, $costo);
    $sql2->bindValue(4, $categoria);
    $sql2->bindValue(5, $moneda);
    $sql2->bindValue(6, $subtotal);
    $sql2->bindValue(7, $total);
    $sql2->bindValue(8, $estado);
    $sql2->bindValue(9, $id_producto);
    $sql2->bindValue(10, $id_usuario);
    $sql2->bindValue(11, $numero_Dproducto);

    $sql2->execute();
  }
```

Comment: Creo que el problema está en el campo que actualizas con `now()`. En las variables `sql` y `sql2` no estás indicando el nombre de la columna en la BD que debe llevar `now()` si no que está puesto a secas. Y si por alguna razón no funcionara, todavía queda la opción: `$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: trate de esa manera, pero de la misma manera no soluciona el problema.

Comment: Pero no queda claro a qué columna de la tabla se seteará el   `now()` ¿?  Pon un `var_dump($conectar->errorInfo());` después del `execute` para ver cuál es el motivo del error.